# Header Remove on a certain window position - Angular- CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm hoping for some assistance on a design/angularJ framework header options. Essentially what I am trying to do is create the effect where the header(navbar) is hidden at the top of the page, and only on the home page while a background video is playing. On scroll the header(navbar) will appear again. I have considered a but of options, but wanted to get your insight before I make a move.

An example of how this works can be seen on  https://vine.co/ you can see it on the home page.

Reminder, I'm using the AngularJS framework so if you are recommending jquery, please wrap it in a directive.

Comment: what have you tried? can you create a plunkr with your current code? personally i would recommend a body class toggle based on scroll position that changes the visibility of the bar

Comment: yeah like haxxxton said, you need class assign to the header which can toggle the visiblity during scroll event.

Comment: // get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable
var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();

// on scroll, 
$(window).on('scroll',function(){

    // we round here to reduce a little workload
    stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainbottom) {
        $('.nav').addClass('past-main');
    } else {
        $('.nav').removeClass('past-main');
   }

});

Comment: But how do I integrate this into Angular JS